# LayoutRoot not recognized in my project

Tags: wpf

Please see [this](http://docs.telerik.com/devtools/silverlight/controls/radchartview/populating-with-data/static-data) Code behind example

In the line `this.LayoutRoot.Children.Add(chart);`
What does `LayoutRoot` meaning ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just extension to earlier answer, your code should be in below form

```
<MainWindow>
    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
        <telerik:RadCartesianChart>
           <!-- ......... -->
        </telerik:RadCartesianChart>
    </Grid>
</MainWindow>
```

So LayoutRoot is nothing but name of grid which contains RadCartesianChart.

Answer (score 0):

LayoutRoot is the block that englobes their example. In their sample code, the first block is a `<telerik:RadCartesianChart`. The LayoutRoot would be your block that contains it.

For example, in your code it should look like this:

```
<MainWindow>
    <Grid>
        <telerik:RadCartesianChart>
           <!-- ......... -->
        </telerik:RadCartesianChart>
    </Grid>
</MainWindow>
```

So the LayoutRoot would be the Grid. Remember this is just an example, your actual structure very probably doesn't look like this.

Comment: In my example i have all the above except the grid so what should be written ?

Comment: It would mean your layoutroot is the Mainwindow, so instead of this.LayoutRoot.etc, give a name to your mainwindow and write this.mainwindowname.etc.